# How can import a Apex application from a Zip file

Tags: oracle-apex

Few days ago i exported an apex app as a zip file and then deleted the application from the workspace. Now when i am trying to import it its giving me an error "Error processing condition". Is there any way of importing the application back into the workspace.
I extracted the zip file and then tried importing it but got the same error.

[image: Error processing condition. Contact your application administrator.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The export as zip is meant to be used for source code control. If you check in the unzipped files you can see what component in the app was changed between 2 versions, with complete sql files that is a lot harder.
You can import the zipped app with a client like sql, sqlplus or sqlcl by executing the file "install.sql". I don't think you can import the actual zip file through the app - the import is expecting a single sql file.